# Ways of writing $n=2a+b$ with $a$ and $b$ are non-negative integers

Tags: number-theory

For a non-negative number $n$, let $r_n$ be the number of ways of writing
$n = a + 2b$, where $a$ and $b$ are non-negative integers.

For example,
$5 = 1  \cdot 5 + 2 \cdot  0 = 3 \cdot  1 + 1 \cdot  2 = 1 \cdot  1 + 2 \cdot  2$,
so $r_5 = 3$.

My question is I have found the rule that:

$r_0=r_1=1$,

$r_2=r_3=2$,

$r_4=r_5=3$,

$r_6=r_7=4$,

......

$r_{n-1}=r_{n}=\frac{n+1}{2}$ where $n$ is odd.

But how can we prove this rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $a$ is determined by $n$ and $b$ via $a=n-2b$, so $r_n$ is the number of valid choices for $b$. Since $a$ and $b$ must be nonnegative, we get $b\geq 0$ and $n-2b\geq 0$, so $\frac n2\geq b \geq 0$. If $n=2k$ or $2k+1$, then the only integer values $b$ can take are $0, 1, \ldots, k$ so there are $k+1$ choices. In particular, in the case $n=2k+1$, $$k+1=\frac{n-1+2}{2}=\frac{n+1}{2}$$ which is exactly the formula you found.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $n=2k$. Then we can use $0$ or $1$ or $2$ or $\dots$ or $k$ two-dollar coins, a total of $k$ choices.

Let $n=2k+1$. Then we can use $0$ or $1$ or $2$ or $\dots$ or $k$ two-dollar coins, a total of $k$ choices.